# Why is an ObservableObject embedded in an EnvironmentObject not adding new items to a List

Tags: swift, object, observable, swiftui-list

I am learning SwiftUI and modified an existing example because I wanted to test if it is possible to have an ObservableObject accessible across views. When reading the documentation I found I should use the @EnvironmentObject for this. I tried this but this does not work: the array persons is filled with new persons (using the debugger) but the UI is not updated. If I use the people property outside of the @EnvironmentObject it works as expected.

My code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var envTest: EnvTest
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(envTest.people.persons) { person in
                Text("\(person.name)")
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.envTest.people.persons.append(Person(id: 4, name: "I am new here"))
            }) {
                Text("Add/Change name")
            }
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let envTest = EnvTest()

    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(envTest)
    }
}

class Person: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    @Published var name: String

    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

class People: ObservableObject {
    @Published var persons: [Person]

    init() {
        self.persons = [
            Person(id: 1, name: "Jabba"),
            Person(id: 2, name: "Polke"),
            Person(id: 3, name: "Lori")]
    }
}

class EnvTest: ObservableObject {
    @ObservedObject var people = People()
}
```

I added the EnvTest to the SceneDelegate using:

```
var window: UIWindow?
var envTest = EnvTest()

func scene(...) {

    let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context).environmentObject(envTest)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems to fix to get to the result you want:

1. Import `Combine` and replace `@ObservedObject` in `EnvTest` with `@Published`
2. Manually trigger `EnvTest.objectWillChange` when the 'people' property changes by adding a subscriber to `objectWillChange` of the `people` property.

The reason for these two changes is to do with how `ObservableObject` works. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject) tells us

> An ObservableObject synthesizes an `objectWillChange` publisher that emits the changed value before any of its @Published properties changes.

If you don't have a `@Published` property then the `People.objectWillChange` publisher won't emit anything. Once we've fixed that, when we change the `persons` property on `People` that triggers the `People.objectWillChange` publisher to emit a value. However, a second problem is revealed, that SwiftUI is listening to the `EnvTest.objectWillChange` publisher, so we won't see the UI update. This is why we have to manually call `send` on the `EnvTest.objectWillChange` publisher when we receive a value from the `People.objectWillChange` publisher, to inform SwiftUI that it needs to generate new Views.

It would be nice if Combine automatically propagated `objectWillChange` calls when you put a `@Published` property wrapper on a property of a type conforming to `ObservableObject`. Similarly, it would be nice if SwiftUI watched the lowest `ObservableObject` rather than the top level one (i.e. in this case watched `People` instead of `EnvTest`). Perhaps this will be introduced in the future, because the current solution of manually linking the two is a pain and won't scale well.

The full solution in code to do what you wanted is:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var envTest: EnvTest
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(envTest.people.persons) { person in
                Text("\(person.name)")
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.envTest.people.persons.append(Person(id: 4, name: "I am new here"))
            }) {
                Text("Add/Change name")
            }
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let envTest = EnvTest()

    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(envTest)
    }
}

class Person: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    @Published var name: String

    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

class People: ObservableObject {
    @Published var persons: [Person]

    init() {
        self.persons = [
            Person(id: 1, name: "Jabba"),
            Person(id: 2, name: "Polke"),
            Person(id: 3, name: "Lori")]
    }
}

class EnvTest: ObservableObject {
    @Published var people = People()

    init(people: People = People()) {
        self.people = people
        people.objectWillChange.receive(subscriber: Subscribers.Sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in }) {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I could never have figured this out myself.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems this is not possible, but as my understanding of Swift got better, I know I can easily share the observable between views without embedding it in an EnvironmentObject.